# How can I localize image resources inside a Cocoapod?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, cocoapods

It's pretty straightforward to add different lproj folders with all the images to my development pod which show up fine in my workspace.

If I then want to use different images for different languages I have to add the languages to the `Info` tab of the `Pods` project first, if I do this and localize all the images everything works fine.

But of course as soon as I do a `pod update` the `Pods` project gets recreated and the localization is lost.

Is there a way to tell the podfile to recreate the project with multiple localization languages?
Or is there another way to have multiple images for different languages inside a cocoapod?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, the least hassle way I found is to let cocoapods use the `en.lproj/` folders as regular resources, after a `pod update` they will be added as folders in the project.

After which you can remove the reference to the folder, and re-add it (but as a group, not as a folder), which will result in (automatically) adding all localizations for those files.

This is not ideal but works for me (a cocoapod that isn't updated often, with only two languages).